# How many time I have to start startSmsRetriever to retrive SMS multiple time using SMS Retriever API?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, sms-retriever-api

I need to retrive SMS in different activities several times.

For SMS retrive I start smsRetriver in my activity.

```
SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(context);
Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();
```

If I have to to do it **every time** or **once** in an Application?

Comment: Once anywhere in you app is fine, could be activity or your app. Think of registering a broadcast, this is just like that also note that after registering, it will throw a Timeout after 5 minutes.

Comment: As far as I know, once the `SmsRetrieverClient` starts, it waits for ONE matching SMS until the timeout of 5 minutes. If you have multiple activity, you will need to call this method every time. Check this [blog](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827) for more details.